# Run Background Task as Loop in Swift

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift

I know that I can create a background task like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // do some task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update some UI
    });
});
```

([Source](https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/))

**How can I create a background task which executes a code block every `n` seconds and how can I stop this task?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Combine `NSTimer` and your background code. That will be like:

## Objective-C

```
- (void)someBackgroundTask:(NSTimer *)timer {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
   ^{
      // do some task
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update some UI
      });
  });
}
```

and then call this method through timer

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(someBackgroundTask:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
```

to stop that timer and the background execution

```
[timer invalidate];
```

## Swift 2.2

```
func someBackgroundTask(timer:NSTimer) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), 
     { () -> Void in

        println("do some background task")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            println("update some UI")

        })
    })
}
```

and then call this method through timer

```
var timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, 
                          target: self, 
                        selector: "someBackgroundTask:",
                        userInfo: nil, 
                         repeats: true)
```

to stop that timer and the background execution

```
timer.invalidate()
```

## Swift 3 and later

```
func someBackgroundTask(timer:Timer) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.background.qosClass).async {
        print("do some background task")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("update some UI")
        }
    }
}
```

and create/invoke timer as

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { 
              timer in

              self.someBackgroundTask(timer: timer)
            }
```

`invalidate` method is same.

Comment: it should be "let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(..."

Comment: Actually i'm pretty sure they are the same thing in swift, as they both init the NSTimer.

Comment: @PatelJigar, change `withTimeInterval: 1.0` to `withTimeInterval: 30 * 60`

Comment: @x4h1d, if you have few minutes please tell me if there is something as "Synchronize multiple background tasks, where one task runs every 30 seconds and another runs as per request (e.g. button click or something)", what does SYNCHRONIZE means exactly, today I was interviewed for middle iOS developer position and this was one of the question, should I post separate question? just not sure if such thing exist, thanks!

Comment: @Aamir, background tasks, by definition, are asynchronous, but you can achieve concurrency among those tasks. Check Rob's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045860/how-to-run-multiple-background-thread-tasks-one-at-a-time-swift-3).

Comment: Btw, you should have opened a new question, maybe, in reddit or quora.