# Difference of async blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**What is the difference between the following async blocks?**

[Run Background Task as Loop in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561476/background-task-as-loop-in-swift)

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
  dispatch_after(
    dispatch_time(
      DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
      Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    ),
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

and:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
        println("do some background task")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            println("update some UI")

        })
})
```

Comment: Excuse me? All the methods involved have excellent documentation, and they all behave exactly as documented. Apart from that, one uses a closure that we don't know, the other calls println twice. What is your actual question?

Comment: It looks like you just copied stuff from an answer to another question, destroying every context, and therefore turning it absolutely meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code doesn't perform a task in the background - it waits until `delay` is up and then calls the closure supplied as an argument to the `delay` function.

The second code performs a task in the background. `dispatch_async` is useful for performing tasks that could block the main thread, fetching some data from a network for example. If the main thread is blocked the UI will become unresponsive until the task is complete, which is obviously very undesirable! Also, there is a second `dispatch_async` call, this time using the main thread, because UI should always be updated on the main thread.