# Run a thread continuously without blocking main thread in swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos

I wrote a code and I need to run it continuously. Initially I used `RunLoop.current.run()`. It works fine. The problem is it blocks the main thread. How can I run it in background continuously without blocking.

**Basic class structure**:

```
class Keylogger
{
    func start()
    {
        let observer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

        /* Connected and Disconnected Call Backs */
        IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(manager, Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback, observer)

        IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(manager, Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback, observer)
        /* Input value Call Backs */
        IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(manager, Handle_IOHIDInputValueCallback, observer);
        /* schedule */
        IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(manager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue)
        print("Started")
    }
}
```

And in main.swift

```
var logger = Keylogger()
logger.start()
RunLoop.current.run()
// Whatever written below this will not be executed obviously
```

I used `DispatchQueue` before for background tasks( which is just a piece of code) but how to execute it continuously?

**I tried this**:

```
var d = Keylogger()
var ff = {
    d.start()
}

var f = DispatchQueue(label: "Keylogger", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent)
f.async(execute: ff)



while true
{}
```

But the `start()` of `Keylogger` is never executed.

I thought of creating executable and running the executable through `NSTask`. Other than this is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could fire a timer repeately which calls your endless task in on a background queue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29564713/1457385

Comment: are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @SkrewEverything yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not understanding the purpose of `RunLoop.current.run()`.

Your code works only when your program is running. Constantly.

Your keylogger code is ran on an another thread. So, to keep that thread alive, the main thread must be active. That is the reason for `RunLoop.current.run()`.

So, try to use callbacks(like keylogger is using) and schedule it on another thread. Or, do everything you want and place `RunLoop.current.run()` at the very end of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.